# Symbolising an argument in Logic

Tags: logic

I have to translate the following argument into symbolic notation of logic.

**If either Argentina or Brazil joins the alliance then if either Chille or Ecuador boycotts it then although Peru does not boycott it Venezuela boycotts it.If either Peru or Nicaragua does not boycott it then Uruguay join the alliance. Therefore if Argentina joins the alliance then if Chile boycotts then Urugway will join the alliance.**

Which I translate into the following :

The premises are :

(($A \lor B) \rightarrow ((C \lor E) \rightarrow (\sim P  \land V)))$

$\sim (P \lor N) \rightarrow U$

The conclusion is :

($ A \rightarrow (C \rightarrow U))$.

Where I have used the 1st letter to mean the actions. $A$ means Argentina joins the alliance. $ C$ means Chile boycotts it. $B$ means Brazil joins the alliance. $E$ means Ecuador boycotts it. $P$ means Peru boycotts it.(negation means Peru doesn't boycott) $U$ means Uruguay joins the alliance. $V$ means Venezuela boycotts it. $N$ means Nicaragua boycotts it.

Am I right in translating it ? If wrong then hope to get corrected.Thank You.

Comment: $$\neg P\lor \neg N\Longrightarrow U $$ is how I understand the second premise. Right now you have written: "If neither Peru nor Nicaragua boycot it, then ... 
but that is not what is said.

Comment: Yes .you are right ! I mistaken it.What about the other premises ?

Comment: Looks okay to me. Do you also have to verify the conclusion or you only have to translate it into symbols?

Comment: If you use two letters for each action, it is much easier to read: $XJ$ for "X joins the alliance", $XB$ for "X boycotts the alliance". So   
premise one: $(AJ\lor BJ)\rightarrow [(CB\lor EB)\rightarrow (\neg PB\land VB)]$. Premise 2:  $(\neg PB\lor \neg NB)\rightarrow UG$  conclusion: $AJ\rightarrow (CB\rightarrow UJ)$

Comment: I also have to verify the conclusion @AlvinLepik.

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake here.
The first one would be - (A v B) > {(C v E) > (~P • V)}
the second one would be -  (~P v ~N) > U
And the last one -   A > (C > U)